# SQL Collect duplicates to one place? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, join, group-by

Sorry I'm new here and I'm also new with SQL and can't really explain my problem in the title...

So I have a TV show database, and there I have a Genre column, but for a TV show there are multiple Genres stored, so when I'm selecting all my TV Shows how can I combine them?

It needs to look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EhBj.png

So I have to combine the string together, here is my code so far what I wrote:

```
SELECT title,
               year,
               runtime,
               MIN(name) as name,
               ROUND(rating, 1) as rating,
               trailer,
               homepage
        FROM shows
        JOIN show_genres 
            on shows.id = show_genres.show_id 
        JOIN genres 
            on show_genres.genre_id = genres.id
        GROUP BY title,
               year,
               runtime,
               rating,
               trailer,
               homepage
        ORDER BY rating DESC
        LIMIT 15;
```

I also have some other stuff here, that's my exerciese tasks! Thanks!

Also here is the relationship model:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M89ho.png

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: to GMB: it's postgresSQL,
to Igor: it's not a debugging problem, I just pasted my already written code, it has nothing do to with my current problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need string aggregation - in Postgres, you can use `string_agg()` for this.

For efficiency, I would recommend moving the aggregation to a correlated subquery or a lateral join rather than aggregating in the outer query, so:

```
SELECT 
    s.title,
    s.year,
    s.runtime,
    g.genre_names,
    ROUND(s.rating, 1) as rating,
    s.trailer,
    s.homepage
FROM shows s
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT string_agg(g.name, ', ') genre_names
    FROM show_genres sg
    INNER JOIN genres g ON g.id = sg.genre_id
    WHERE sg.show_id = s.id
) g ON 1 = 1
ORDER BY s.rating DESC
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: Thank you so much!